# How to creating an in-place editable form for embedded documents using mongoid in Rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I have two models User(main document) and Contact(embedded document in User). I'm showing a list of contacts when displaying a user. I was wondering if there is a suggested way of creating an in place editable form for all the contacts that are shown on the same page.

Really appreciate an sort of examples.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to employ a bit of Javascript to hook into the view to update the object via AJAX.  There are ways to do this using `ember-rails` right out of the box, but you can pick any framework you like.  Essentially, you'll need to be able to do a RESTful update of the user, making use of the `remote: true` parameter on your Rails form.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah, this is what I did. Just saw your response.